# Consider Inheritance Hierarchy with KClass

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, reflection

I want to pass a type (as `KClass`) as a parameter to a function. However, the specific type might be a subtype of the parameter, but the compiler always expect the specific type specified in the function signature.

```kotlin
interface A
class Implementation1 : A
class Implementation2 : A

fun showType(aType: KClass<A>) {
    println(aType.simpleName)
}

showType(Implementation1::class) // ⚡wrong parameter type
```

[Executable example](https://pl.kotl.in/OPC1CYq_w)

If I try to compile this, I get:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is KClass<Implementation1> but KClass<A> was expected
```

So, while Implementation1 implements the expected interface `A`, inheritance seems to be ignored with reflection.

Is there a way to accept derived types with reflection?

Comment: Kotlin's generics are subtly different from Java's. Check out the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html). In this case, you want `KClass<out A>`.

Comment: Thank you, @Jorn! If you would submit your answer as official answer, I would accept it. And you'd become 10 reputation points richer immediately 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8681/jorn) pointed out, the type parameter `A` needs to be *covariant* using `out` annotation:

```kotlin
fun showType(aType: KClass<out A>) { 
  // "out" does the trick  ^^^ 
  println(aType.simpleName)
}
```

As such subtypes of `A` are accepted as `A`.

See [documentation about generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html).